# Set up SFML with Code::Blocks on windows 8

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks, sfml, windows-8.1

I had Code::Blocks working on my other Windows 8 computer using the GNU GCC compiler, but when I copied and pasted everything exactly the way it was into my other Windows 8 computer, my projects stopped working. Currently, it throws this error:

> mingw32-g++.exe -LC:\Matthew\Documents\SFML-1.6\lib  -o bin\Debug\Game.exe obj\Debug\Main.o   -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -static-libgcc-static-libstdc++ -lsfml-graphics-s-d -lsfml-window-s-d -lsfml-system-s-d -static-libgcc-static-libstdc++
>
> mingw32-g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-static-libgcc-static-libstdc++'
> mingw32-g++.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-static-libgcc-static-libstdc++'

I looked up the problem and found one place recommending that I remove whatever is listed as an unrecognized command from my linker settings, but when I do that it says that it "cannot find" any of the other things I have in my linker. Is there an easy solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have two compiler switches concatenated together when they should be separated with a whitespace:

> -static-libgcc-static-libstdc++

Try modifying the linking command to:

> g++.exe -**static-libgcc** -**static-libstdc++** -LC:\Matthew\Documents\SFML-1.6\lib -o bin\Debug\Game.exe obj\Debug\Main.o -lsfml-graphics-s -lsfml-window-s -lsfml-system-s -lsfml-graphics-s-d -lsfml-window-s-d -lsfml-system-s-d

Comment: So are you saying that I should put that in the other linker options under build options for my project? Now it looks like this: -static-libgcc
-static-libstdc++
-lsfml-graphics-s
-lsfml-window-s
-lsfml-system-s

Comment: the -static-libgcc works, but it stills says that -static-libstd++ is unrecognized

Comment: Note that it's `-static-libstdc++`.

Comment: Oops, thats what I meant to put, I just messed up typing it into the comment

Comment: which version of mingw are you using? Anything gcc 4.5.2 and later should support that switch.

Comment: Ok, theres the problem. Looks like I still have 4.4.0, I will update and try it

Comment: I updated my mingw and now have gcc 4.8.1 and both commands now work. I also rebuilt the SFML libraries using the new version, but it still tells me that it cannot find any of my links to the SFML 1.6 links, it just says "cannot find -lsfml-graphics-s" or the same thing but for a different part of SFML such as -lsfml-window-s

Comment: Maybe the recompiled versions have different names? Best thing to do is check the build output to see what they are and update it in your project.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Somehow the search directories I had set up were wrong even though the directories I told it to search were correct. I copied and pasted the paths into it and now it works.